# SQL no DB MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu tenho a seguinte situação, um cadastro com 5 campos sendo eles:
Tipo1, Tipo2, Tipo3, Tipo4 e valor

Os 4 campos de tipo são campos combos, onde pode ser selecionado a opção todos, ou outra opção qualquer.

Pra exemplificar:

```
<select class="form-control" id="tipo1" name="tipo1">
    <option value="" selected>TODOS</option>
    <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="3">Opção 2</option>
    ...
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="tipo2" name="tipo2">
...
```

Até ai tudo bem, está funcionando ok.
No MySQL eu tenho a seguinte situação

```
Id  Tipo1  Tipo2  Tipo3  Tipo4  Valor
1   1      Null   2      3      100.00
```

Obs.:

1. Os 4 tipos não podem ser nulos ao mesmo tempo.
2. Pode acontecer de o tipo1, ou tipo2 ou tipo3 estar preenchido e todos os demais tipos serem nulos.

Pra contextualizar, isso é um cadastro de metas, que dependendo da situação e do valor se foi ultrapassado, deve deixar passar, ou bloquear.

Estou usando PHP e MySQL, meu problema é fazer uma consulta se a situação existe no banco, não estou conseguindo enxergar como fazer isso.
Não sei se consegui ser claro, e pode ser que a resposta esteja na minha frente, mais já quebrei bastante a cabeça e não saiu nada, então resolvi pedir ajuda. hehe.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua pergunta, você está com problema na hora de executar a query no banco e retornar uma certa situação, é isso?

Comment: Acho que sim, @RicardoPontual. Scussel, favor especificar a "certa situação" que você procura.

Comment: Você quer que a query falhe se os 4 campos forem Null ou quer checar isso no front/backend ? O problema é na hora de pesquisar ou não quer inserir com os 4 nulos ?

Answer (score 0):

> meu problema é fazer uma consulta se a situação existe no banco

Cara pelo que entendi a única situação que não pode ocorrer é se os quatro campos são nulos ao mesmo tempo, qualquer outra é aceita. Parece que você não validou isso antes pois aí não teria sentido fazer a consulta no banco.

O sql para verificar os casos nessa situação 'errada' seria:

```
select id from tabela 
where tipo1 is null 
and tipo2 is null 
and tipo3 is null 
and tipo4 is null
```

Lembrando que

```
tipo1 is null (campo nulo)
```

é uma expressão diferente de

```
tipo1 = "" (string vazia)
```